# Get TOP(1) Date and Time of Status table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT RIGHT(LEFT(a.JobOrders, 16), 3) as OrderSuffix, COUNT(1) as TotalCount
FROM Orders a, Status b
WHERE a.JobOrders = b.JobOrders
    AND b.Status = 'Finished'
GROUP BY RIGHT(LEFT(a.JobOrders, 16), 3)
ORDER BY TotalCount Desc
```

Is there a way  to include in that `SELECT` query the `TOP (1)` `Date` and `TIME` fields of table `Status` where `RIGHT(LEFT(a.JobOrders, 16), 3) = <3 letter value>`?

What I am currently doing is I get first the distinct values, `OrderSuffix`. Put it on a datatable. For each row, I am sending an SQL where `RIGHT(LEFT(a.JobOrders, 16), 3) = <3 letter value>` to get the `TOP (1)` `Date` and `Time`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: Either aggregate function or APPLY operation might do this, but it's not clear in the question how the 3 letter value impacts the whole query. Perhaps some sample data and results would illustrate this for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For details of two common approaches how to do the `top-n-per-group` query see the [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6841605/4116017) question.

The query below uses the `ROW_NUMBER` approach.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        RIGHT(LEFT(a.JobOrders, 16), 3) as OrderSuffix
        ,COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY RIGHT(LEFT(a.JobOrders, 16), 3)) as TotalCount
        ,b.Date
        ,b.Time
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (PARTITION BY RIGHT(LEFT(a.JobOrders, 16), 3) 
            ORDER BY b.Date DESC, b.Time DESC) as rn
    FROM
        Orders a
        INNER JOIN Status b ON a.JobOrders = b.JobOrders
    WHERE
        b.Status = 'Finished'
)
SELECT
    OrderSuffix
    ,TotalCount
    ,Date
    ,Time
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY TotalCount Desc;
```